# jQuery-file-upload with PHP class

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery file upload from blueImp to upload files to a web directory. For the most part it works, tho it consistently drops a file. I use the following for an ajax request. This loops through each of the files uploaded and images.php writes to DB.

```
//On successfull upload of pages
    $('#albumPages.fileupload').bind('fileuploadalways',function(e,data) {
        //Loop through each page and return object and write to DB
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var filename = data.result[0].name;
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "../queries/images.php",
                data: {file: filename}
            });
        });
        //CSS to change GUI

        $('#albumPages.fileupload').bind('fileuploadstop' , function(e,data) {
            $('.modal_uploader_pages').css("display","none");
            $('.modal_uploader_back').css("display","block");
            $('.breadcrumbs').css("background-position","left 128px");
        });
    });
```

**The DB write**

```
INSERT INTO galleryimage 
            (
                galleryId
                ,image
                ,OrgImageName
                ,clientRef
                -- ,sort
                ,layout
            ) VALUES (
                '{$galleryID}'
                ,'{$imageID}'
                ,'{$originalName}'
                ,'{$clientRef}'
                -- ,'{$order}'
                ,'{$galleryLayout}'
            )"
```

The error that I receive using the 'Network' tab from Chrome  Developer tool is a 500 Internal Server Error. Any insight or direction on trouble shooting this issue. I have SSH'd into the server to check the php error log and nothing there in regards to this event.

Comment: Did you try running your ajax without the file attached? If so, what happens then?

Comment: the ajax request doesn't contain the actual file. It just grabs the filename. The file is getting written with jQuery-file-upload php class...

Comment: Okay, I can't copy the whole code so I can't specifically say: here is the answer. what you should try: comment the ajax stuff and try the $.each loop, try that first. If that works, step 1. Try the variable, check if the variable exists. Now, run the ajax and do a simple echo in the php file. Just an echo and try to catch that value, so you will know if the ajax is working. From now on, you can expand your code. Use var_dump, print_r and console.log to see what you variables are and what they are doing.

Comment: What are you doing in the images.php class? Can you copy its content in a JSFiddle (only to get a look at it). Blueimp is used to work in background, since it open a connection with you server and sends back (if you want) the updates on the file upload. Hence it is important to see what happen when you call the PHP class. Moreover, are you using such a framework (ZEND, Symfony and so on)?